# Audio source with axios stream?

Tags: axios, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I have an HTML5 audio control and would his src property is pointing to my middleware, an express / node server that delivers a streaming mp3 file.

On the middleware I'm using `res.pipe()` to output the mp3 file.
It's working great with one caveat: I can't send my authorization header.
So I want to use axios to access my middleware which works fine but I can't figure out how to "feed" the audio element.

If I do:

```
const response = axios.get('/api/stream',{requestHeaders:'stream'});\
myAudio.src = response;
```

It throws an error and I'm block from there...

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: It's far better if you find some other way to authenticate, such as via querystring in the URL.  Otherwise, you'll have to use MediaSource Extensions which have a lot of compatibility problems.  (For starters, you'd have to mux your MP3 audio into an MP4 container.)  And then, you'd have to write a ton of extra code to make it work.  The only other way is to use a Service Worker, but this has compatibility issues with streaming on Safari.  It also doesn't work sometimes, such as depending on how the user refreshes the page.

Comment: Yes agreed. In fact it was super easy to add a token to my src url... Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Finally managed to pass a token as a get parameters instead of trying to use axios.

Comment: This answer is [being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415185/522444).